# emit file with elementRef from child to parent in angular

Tags: angular, dom

I'm trying to create a component that user select file and then I pass file with reference to parent component and then upload file. For this, I'm create a component like below:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matching-upload-file',
  templateUrl: './matching-upload-file.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matching-upload-file.component.scss']
})
export class MatchingUploadFileComponent {

  @ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload: ElementRef;
  @Output() selectedFile = new EventEmitter<File[]>();

  constructor() {
  }

  onClick() {
    if (this.fileUpload) {
      this.fileUpload.nativeElement.click();
    }
  }

  onFileSelected(event) {
    const files = event.dataTransfer ? event.dataTransfer.files : event.target.files;

    this.onClick();

    // Then upload file and is successful

    // But when I pass to parent component and upload, file of formData is empty.
    
    this.selectedFile.emit(files);

  }

}
```

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary"
        (click)="fileUpload.click()">
  <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  label
</button>
<input #fileUpload
       id="fileUpload"
       hidden
       type="file"
       (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
>
```

Now I want convert above code to a component and use it in another components and when user select file, selected file pass to the parent component as output and then upload from parent. For this I change below:

First add output to child component:

```
  @Output() selectedFile = new EventEmitter<File[]>();
```

But when I pass file to parent, the reference of file not exist and on request file is empty:

```
upload(file: File, url: string, token: string) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', token);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    const req = new HttpRequest(
      'POST',
      url,
      formData,
      {reportProgress: true, headers}
    );

    this.httpClient.request(req).subscribe(
      (response) => {
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      });
  }
```

**Parent component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-matching',
  templateUrl: './matching.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matching.component.scss']
})
export class MatchingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private uploadFileService: UploadFileService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  recieveFiles(files: File[]) {
    // Upload files[0]
    this.uploadFileService.upload(files[0], 'url', 'token');
    // But file in formData is empty.
  }

}
```

```
<app-matching-upload-file (selectedFile)="recieveFiles($event)"></app-matching-upload-file>
```

I'm try some other solution, for example: initialize **ElementRef** from parent and pass to child as input or pass **ElementRef** from child to parent; but non of these changes worked. How can I pass file with references from child to parent?

Comment: can you show the HTML code of your parent ? How do you trigger the `upload` method ? How do you listen to the `@Output selectedFile` ?

Comment: I added the parent codes, ts and html. @Random

Comment: Seems ok to me :( You may have to add logs (or debug it in chrome devtools) to follow your File, and see when it contains something, and when the data is lost...

Comment: I noticed something, if I implement **upload** function in parent component, every thing is ok and upload file successfully, but when I pass file to **UploadFileService**, file not append on **dataForm**, @Random